# Lebesgue Measure of Disk is $\pi r^2$ using Fubinis Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Sorry for being unhelpful with this question, I normally do try to have a good stab at questions before posting them here but I seem to have mathematicians block today! Could anyone just give me a very brief outline of how I can find show the Lebesgue Measure of Disk is $\pi r^2$ using Fubinis Theorem?

Thanks a lot and sorry for not putting a lot of effort into this question.

**EDIT**

I have decided to have a stab. Notice that $\lambda^2=\lambda^1 \times \lambda^1$ and a similar result for Borel Sigma Algebras.

Hence $\lambda^2(D)=\lambda^1\times\lambda^1(D):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda^1(D_x)d\lambda^1(x)$

Where $E_x:=\{y \in \mathbb{R} : (x,y)\in E\}$ for any $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Here we have $D_x= \chi_{[-r,r]}\cdot\chi_{[-\sqrt{r^2-x^2},\sqrt{r^2-x^2}]} $  (from simple geometry)

And hence $\lambda^2(D)= \int_{[-r,r]}\lambda^1(\chi_{[-\sqrt{r^2-x^2},\sqrt{r^2-x^2}]})d\lambda^1(x)= \int_{[-r,r]}2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}d\lambda^1(x) $

Which I can then solve. But I dont think I have used Fubinis theorem?

Comment: The equality $\lambda^2(D) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda^1(D_x) \,d\lambda^1(x)$ is an application of Fubini's theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your notations, we must calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D}(x,y) \lambda^2(x,y)$

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let $D_x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}| (x,y)\in D\}$

We can write $\chi_{D}(x,y) = \chi_{[-r,r]}(x).\chi_{D_x}(y)$

From Fubini

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D}(x,y) \lambda^2(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{[-r,r]}(x).\chi_{D_x}(y)d\lambda^1(y)\right)d\lambda^1(x)$

$= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[-r,r]}(x) \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{D_x}(y)d\lambda^1(y)\right)d\lambda^1(x)$

$= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[-r,r]}(x) \lambda^1(D_x)d\lambda^1(x)$

Comment: Thank you indeed! Great answer :)